# Seber, Ex. 1.b.3 - Calculating variance and showing unbiasedness

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, regression

Exercise 3 of Sebers *Linear Regression Analysis* states the following:
[image]

I tried to solve both problems but only managed to (kinda) solve the first one and have no idea how to tackle the second one. First, however, let me post the solutions:
[image]

For 1), I tried to find the minimum variance by minimizing w/ the Lagrangian that is also stated in the solution. I proceeded as follows:

$var(\overline X_W) = var(\sum_i w_ix_i) = \sum_i var(w_ix_i) = \sum_i w_i^2 var(x_i) = \sum_i w_i^2 \sigma_i^2$.

This I minimized w.r.t to the constraint $\sum_i w_i = 1$ and obtained the Lagrangian $L = \Bigl(\sum_i w_i^2 \sigma_i^2 - w_i \Bigr)+1$.

Setting up the first order conditions gave me $2w_i\sigma_i ^2 = 0$ and the Lagrangian multiplier itself. What I got out of it is that $2w_i\sigma_i ^2 = 0 \implies w_i \propto \frac{1}{\sigma_i ^2}$. However, the solution states that the proportionality factor is $a$. The other thing is that I have no idea what they could mean by substituting $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} w_i = w_n$ instead of using the Lagrange multiplier.

With b), I don't even know how to start. I tried rewriting it multiple times but it lead me nowhere unfortunately. To summarize, my questions are:

1. Why did Seber use proportionality factor $a$ instead of the $\frac{1}{2}$ that I got?
2. What could he mean by substituting $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} w_i = w_n$?
3. Why do the equalities in the solution to exercise b) hold true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $2w_i \sigma_i^2 = 0$ is clearly wrong since that would imply $w_i = 0$. How did you conclude $w_i \propto 1/\sigma_i^2$? Applying the Lagrange multiplier theorem directly without making any simplifications, the Lagrange multiplier equations are
   \begin{align}
   2\sigma_i^2w_i &= \lambda \\
   \sum_{i}w_i &= 1.
   \end{align}
   From the first equation, $w_i = \frac{\lambda}{2\sigma_i^2}$, then from the second equation, $\frac{\lambda}{2} = \frac{1}{\sum_{i}\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}$, so $w_i = \frac{1}{\sum_{j}\frac{1}{\sigma_j^2}}\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}$.
2. That substitution is a way to frame what looks like a constrained optimization problem into an unconstrained problem. You could minimize the function $v(w_1, \dots, w_{n - 1}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sigma_i^2w_i^2$ over the region $\{(w_1, \dots, w_{n - 1}) : w_1, \dots, w_{n - 1} \geq 0, w_1 + \dots + w_{n - 1} \leq 1\}$. Here $w_n = 1 - (w_1 + \dots + w_{n - 1})$, so the problem is fully specified.
3. Here is repeated use of the equality $E(f^2) = Var(f) + E(f)^2$, which holds for every probability space and every random variable $f$. Note that $\sum_{i}w_i(X_i - \bar{X}_w)^2$ is the variance of $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ with respect to the probability mass function $(w_1, \dots, w_n)$. Hence
   \begin{align}
   \sum_{i}w_i(X_i - \bar{X}_w)^2 &= \sum_{i}w_iX_i^2 - \bar{X}_w^2. 
   \end{align}
   He goes on to take expectations of both sides and use the identity again, then does algebra to arive at the final answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right about question 1 - I spotted my mistake but fixed it. However, I still have two more questions: For answer 2), how would I tackle the unconstrained optimization problem? For answer 3), why would  $\sum_{i}w_i(X_i - \bar{X}_w)^2 = \sum_{i}w_iX_i^2 - \bar{X}_w^2$ follow from the fact that $\sum_{i}w_i(X_i - \bar{X}_w)^2$ is the variance of $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ with   $(w_1, \dots, w_n)$ as the probability mass function? I did the calculations w/ the sums and it turned out that I got the same result but I'm wondering whether there is a shorter way to see why it follows.

Comment: Fyi: I don't know much more optimization than what is taught in an elementary real analysis class. I already tried setting the gradient equal to 0 and this time I (again) got $2w_i\sigma_i ^2 = 0$ so now I'm at the point you described in answer 1, no?

Comment: @l337n00b I said the general result is $E(f^2) = Var(f) + E(f)^2$. This is proven by $$E(f^2) = E((f - E(f) + E(f))^2) = E((f - E(f))^2 + E(f)^2 + 2(f - E(f))E(f)) = E((f - E(f))^2) + E(f)^2.$$ You apply this to the probability measure on $\{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ with probabilities $w_1, \dots, w_n$.

Comment: @l337n00b You didn't compute the gradient correctly because you missed $\frac{\partial w_n}{\partial w_i} = -1$ for $i < n$. In real analysis we learn that for a function defined on an open set, at a maximum the derivative must vanish. This is called unconstrained optimization because you are maximizing over an open set, possibly with boundary included. Constrained optimization is when you are maximizing over a lower dimensional surface. In this case you can frame the problem as constrained optimization over the surface $\{(w_1, \dots, w_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : w_1 + \dots + w_n = 1\}$.

Comment: @l337n00b Note in the constrained optimization, the gradient need not vanish at the maximum. However, the gradient will be a multiple of the gradient of the constraint function. This is the method of Lagrange Multipliers.