# Seber, Ex. 1.b.3) - Unconstrained optimization problem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, optimization

In one of my [previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4824599/seber-ex-1-b-3-calculating-variance-and-showing-unbiasedness), I tried to solve the following exercise:

[image]

Now the solution to exercise 3a) mentions that one may alternatively substitute $w_n = \sum_{i=1} ^{n-1} w_i$ and turn the problem into an unconstrained optimization problem (which was also pointed out by a stackexchange member in the comments of my previous question). However, now I'm stuck.

So far I have formulated the variance as $var(\overline X) = v(w_1,...w_{i-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i ^2 \sigma_i ^2$. Since $w_n = \sum_i w_i \implies w_n = 1- \sum_{j = 1}^n w_j$ I can express $var(\overline X)$ in this way.

Then I tried to compute the gradient by calculating each $\frac{d}{dw_i}$ as follows: $\frac{d}{dw_i} = 2w_i \sigma_i^2 + \frac{d}{dw_i}\Bigl(w_n ^2 \sigma_n ^2\Bigr) = 2w_i \sigma_i^2 + 2\sigma_n^2 w_n \frac{dw_n}{dw_i} =2w_i\sigma_i^2 - 2\sigma_n^2 w_n $.

In the minimum, this has to be equal to the zero vector so I tried setting it equal to 0:

$2w_i\sigma_i^2 - 2\sigma_n^2 w_n = 0 \implies 2w_i\sigma_i^2 = 2\sigma_n^2 w_n \implies w_i\sigma_i^2 = \sigma_n^2 w_n$.

This, however, looks very different from Sebers model solution:
[image]

So my question is: **What am I missing?** I have already tried some further simplification/substitution but it lead me nowhere. Please note that I already solved the problem using lagrangians, I'm just trying to explore the alternative right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the $X_i$'s are independent so that
$$V(\mathbf{w}):=\operatorname{var}\big(\sum^n_{j=1}w_jX_j\big)=\sum^n_{j=1}w^2_j\sigma^2_j$$
under the condition
$$\sum^n_{j=1}w_j=1$$

---

Using Lagrange multipliers, one looks for a solution to
$$ \nabla_w(\sum^n_{j=1}w^2_j\sigma^2_j)+\lambda\nabla_w(\sum^n_{j=1}w_j-1)=\boldsymbol{0}$$
where $\nabla_w=(\partial_{w_1},\ldots,\partial_{w_n})$. That is
$$2\sigma^2_jw_j+\lambda=0,\qquad j=1,\ldots, n$$
Then $w_j=-\frac{\lambda}{2\sigma^2_j}$ for $j=1,\ldots, n$.
Adding the $w$'s we get
$$1=-\lambda\sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{2\sigma^2_h}$$
and so, $\lambda=-\frac{1}{\sum^n_{j=1}\frac1{2\sigma^2_j}}$. Hence
$$w_j=\frac{\sigma^{-2}_j}{\sum^n_{k=1}\frac1{\sigma^2_j}}$$

---

If one uses the condition $\sum^n_{j=1}w_j=1$ to reduce the dimension of the problem (by setting $w_n=1-\sum^{n-1}_{j=1}w_j$, for example), then one looks for solutions to
$$\nabla_{w_1,\ldots,w_{n-1}}\left(\Big(1-\sum^{n-1}_{j=1}w_j\Big)^2\sigma^2_n+\sum^{n-1}_{j=1}\sigma^2_jw^2_j\right)=\boldsymbol{0}$$
where $\nabla_{w_1,\ldots,w_{n-1}}=(\partial_{w_1},\ldots,\partial_{w_{n-1}})$. That is

$$-\frac{\sigma^2_n}{\sigma^2_j}\big(1-\sum^{n-1}_{j=1}w_j\big)+w_j=-\frac{\sigma^2_n}{\sigma^2_j}w_n+w_j=0, \quad j=1,\ldots, n-1
$$
Adding over $j=1,\ldots, n-1$
$$-\Big(\sigma^2_nw_n\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_j}\Big)+1-w_n= -\sigma^2_nw_n\Big(\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_j}\Big) +1=0
$$
that is
$$w_n=\frac{\sigma^{-2}_n}{\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_j}}$$
Hence
$$w_j=\frac{\sigma^2_n}{\sigma^2_j}w_n=\frac{\sigma^{-2}_j}{\sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_j}}
$$

---

This partially solves the OP's problem in that the (only) critical point $\hat{\bf{w}}$ satisfies $\hat{w}_j\propto \sigma^{-2}_j$, $j=1,\ldots, n$.

One estimate use second order conditions to make sure that $\hat{w}_j=\frac{\sigma^{-2}_j}{\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_k}}$, $j=1,\ldots,n$ indeed minimizes $V$ under the restriction $w_j\geq0$ and $\sum^n_{j=1}w_j$. I leave that to the OP.

The minimum value of the variance is then
$$V(\hat{\bf{w}})=\frac{1}{\sum^n_{j=1}\sigma^{-2}_j}$$

---

Finally, I present a solution that does not require differentiation. It relies on a well known inequality in probability theory: [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).
As the $n$-tuples $bf{w}=(w_1,\ldots, w_n)$, $w_j>0$, defines a probability measure on the set $\{1,\ldots, n\}$, and the function $g(x)=\frac1x$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$, we have that for any $m$
$$\frac{1}{\sum^n_{j=1}w^2_j\sigma^2_j}=f\big(\sum^n_{j=1}w^2_j\sigma^2_j\big)=f\big(\sum^n_{j=1}w_j \sigma^2_jw_j\big)\leq\sum^n_{j=1}w_j\frac{1}{\sigma^2w_j}=\sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_j}$$
This means that
$$\frac{1}{\sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_j}}\leq \sum^n_{j=1}w^2_j\sigma^2_j$$
This inequality extends by continuity to all $n$-tuples $\mathbf{w}=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$ with $w_j\geq0$ and $\sum^n_{j=1}w_j=1$. The lower bound is attain when $$w_j=\frac{\sigma^2_j}{\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_k}}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, I am sure that **there is a typo** in the text book. In fact, it should be $w_n = 1- \sum_{i=1} ^{n-1} w_i$ **not** $w_n = \sum_{i=1} ^{n-1} w_i$

After using $w_n = 1- \sum_{i=1} ^{n-1} w_i$, the function with the first $n-1$ variables becomes as follows:

$$v(w_1,...w_{n-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} w_i ^2 \sigma_i ^2+\left (1- \sum_{i=1} ^{n-1}w_i \right )^2\sigma_n ^2.$$

**For a while you can ignore** the following required constraints:

$$w_1,\dots,w_{n-1}\ge 0,\sum_{i=1} ^{n-1}w_i\le1$$

and solve the optimization problem without any constraint (which is easier). If you are **lucky** and the obtained optimal solution satisfies all the ignored constraints, then the solution determines an optimal solution for the original problem; otherwise, you need to solve the original problem using the KKT conditions. The idea of ignoring some constraints works in some situations, but it must be used carefully.

Following this idea, and considering that $v(w_1,...w_{n-1})$ is a convex function, to find the optimal solution of the unconstrained problem, we set each partial derivative of $v(w_1,...w_{n-1})$ given above to zero, which yields the following:

$$\sigma^2_n\big(1-\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}w_i\big)=\sigma^2_jw_j, j=1,\dots, n-1.$$

By solving this system, we obtain

$$ w_j=\frac{\frac{1}{\sigma^2_i}}{\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_i}}, j=1,\dots, n-1.$$

As the above solution satisfies the constraints initially ignored, i.e., $w_1,\dots,w_{n-1}\ge 0,\sum_{i=1} ^{n-1}w_i\le 1$, it determines an optimal solution for the original problem; note that we only need to find the value of $ w_n=\frac{\frac{1}{\sigma^2_n}} {\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_i}}$ using $w_n = 1- \sum_{i=1} ^{n-1} w_i$.

Answer (score 0):

**Continue Your Attempt**

The gradient component that you have calculated:

$$
0=
w_{s}\sigma_{s}^{2}-w_{n}\sigma_{n}^{2}
\phantom{x}
\forall
\phantom{x}s\in\{1,...,n-1\}
$$

Let $w_{n}\sigma_{n}^{2} = C$ , then we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
w_{n}&=\frac{C}{\sigma_{n}^{2}} \\
w_{s}&=\frac{C}{\sigma_{s}^{2}}
\phantom{x}
\forall
\phantom{x}s\in\{1,...,n-1\}
\end{aligned}
$$

Isn't this already the answer you are looking for? To obtain $C$, simply use $\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}=1$

**Remarks**

As others have pointed out, the hint is incorrect, the correct hint should be aligned with what you have done:

$$
w_{n} = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}w_{i}
$$